# Synchronous access to Firebase Cloud Firestore with Swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

OK, I just started investigating Firebase. So say I want to populate a simple tableview. It seems that I only have access to async methods to access its local cache? Is this correct?

So this means I need to callback and then populate my own in-memory cache that in turn the tableview delegate methods can then access? So now we effectively have two caches of the same data? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud Firestore client keeps a copy of all data that you're listening to in the memory of your application. Once you remove the last listener for a location, the data is removed from memory.

Because in Firestore, [offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-offline-behavior) is enabled by default:

> For Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default. To disable persistence, set the `PersistenceEnabled` option to `false`.

The client will also persist active and recent data to disk.

And to answer your questions:

> It seems that I only have access to async methods to access its local cache?

Yes, that's right.

> So this means I need to callback and then populate my own in-memory cache that in turn the tableview delegate methods can then access?

You're also right.

> So now we effectively have two caches of the same data?

As long as the listener is active, yes, you'll have two caches.

Comment: Hi Brad! Can I help you with other informations? If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that I only have access to async methods to access its local cache?

Yes, you are correct.

> So this means I need to callback and then populate my own in-memory cache that in turn the tableview delegate methods can then access?

Yes

> So now we effectively have two caches of the same data?

Yes, and normally, you should use the server data, you only use the firebase cache when you don't have internet.